# "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" - why?

Tags: c#, inheritance

With this code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("saturnisko: {0}", UkladSloneczny.saturn.mass);
        }
    }
    public class UkladSloneczny
    {
        private Saturn sat;

        public UkladSloneczny(Saturn sat)
        {
            this.sat = sat;
        }
        public Saturn saturn
        {
            get { return this.sat; }
        }
    }
    public class Saturn
    {
        private int masa;
        public Saturn() { masa = 0; }
        public int mass
        {
            get { return this.masa; }
        }
    }
```

Why I am getting error like so:

```
Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.UkladSloneczny.saturn.get'
```

?

Comment: You need an **instance**.

Comment: [Difference between Static and Non-Static Mehtods](https://sites.google.com/site/jeff00coder00seattle/home/coding/csharp-coding/-what-s-the-difference-between-a-static-method-and-a-non-static-method)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're getting it here: `Console.WriteLine("saturnisko: {0}", UkladSloneczny.saturn.mass);`

`UkladSloneczny` isn't a static class, so you can't call it like that. You need to either make it static or make a `new` instance of the class and *then* call `yourClassInstance.saturn.mass`.

Answer (score 1):

If the `class`, `method` or `property` are not `static` then you have to instantiate the `object` in memory to be able to do anything with it, otherwise the `object` is `null`.

So either:

```
public static class UkladSloneczny
{
    private static Saturn sat;

    public UkladSloneczny(Saturn sat)
    {
        sat = sat;
    }
    public static Saturn saturn
    {
        get { return sat; }
    }
}
```

OR

```
new UkladSloneczny().saturn.mass
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an object for UkladSloneczny:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UkladSloneczny instance = new UkladSloneczny(new Saturn());
        Console.WriteLine("saturnisko: {0}", instance.saturn.mass);
    }
}
```

Or you can make the mass of saturn a static property:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("saturnisko: {0}", Saturn.mass);
    }
}

public class Saturn
{
    private static int masa = 0;
    public Saturn() {  }
    public static int mass
    {
        get { return masa; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it from an instance of UkladSloneczny, like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Saturn saturn = new Saturn();
        UkladSloneczny ukladSloneczny = new UkladSloneczny(saturn);
        Console.WriteLine("saturnisko: {0}", ukladSloneczny.saturn.mass);
    }
}
```